# Catel.IoC.TypeNotRegisteredException: Catel throws exception even though CanResolve returns true

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-5, catel

I have a WPF Application with Catel.Core, Catel.MVVM, Catel.Analyzers and Catel.Fody installed.

When I start the application and try to resolve a Data Access Repository (`ILigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository`) the exception Catel.IoC.TypeNotRegisteredException gets thrown. When I call             `dependencyResolver.CanResolve<ILigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository>();` it returns true.

I made an extension method to register every service and repository in a single place.

```
public static IServiceLocator RegisterDataAccessRepositories(this IServiceLocator services, string dbCon)
{
                services.RegisterInstance(new SpielbetriebDbContext(dbCon));
                services.RegisterType<IDuelleRepository, DuelleRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<IDuellErgebnisseRepository, DuellErgebnisseRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<ILigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository, LigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository>(); // It is registered!
                services.RegisterType<IMitgliederRepository, MitgliederRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<IPartieDetailsRepository, PartieDetailsRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<IPartienRepository, PartienRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<IProtokollierungenRepository, ProtokollierungenRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<ISaetzeRepository, SaetzeRepository>();
                services
                    .RegisterType<ISpielerPartieErgebnisZuordnungenRepository,
                        SpielerPartieErgebnisZuordnungenRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<ISpielerRepository, SpielerRepository>();
                services.RegisterType<IVereineRepository, VereineRepository>();
    
                return services;
}
```

When I debug the application and check the registered types of the ServiceLocator it even shows me that `ILigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository` is registered (field `_registeredTypes`):
[image: Debugging servicelocator]

The extensions get called in OnStartup. I even tried in the constructor of the App class.

```
var serviceLocator = this.GetServiceLocator();
serviceLocator.RegisterDataAccessRepositories(DataConfig.CurrentDbCon); // <--
serviceLocator.RegisterApplicationServices();
```

I tried to call it right away with the Resolve Method

```
var dep = this.GetDependencyResolver();
dep.Resolve<ILigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository>();
dep.CanResolve<ILigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository>(); // returns true
```

What did do I wrong?

Exception Message
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after debugging for quite some time and checking multiple things, I looked into my Data Access Repositories again. And I realized that my repository's implementation had an `internal` constructor instead of a public constructor. The cause was the base Repository, which had an internal constructor. After changing from `internal` to `public` the DI Container resolved the types correctly.

If you are running into this problem, check if your types have **public** constructors.

Bad:

```
internal LigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository(SpielbetriebDbContext context) : base(context)
{
}
```

Good:

```
public LigaMannschaftenZuordnungenRepository(SpielbetriebDbContext context) : base(context)
{
}
```